# Dynamic Columns Pivot returning multiple rows - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to write a PIVOT query on dynamic columns. It works but it is returning multiple rows.

My query is

```
set @query = 'select PanelID, PanelCode, PanelName, EvaluatorID, PersonID, ApplicationID, ' + @cols + ' from (
select 
distinct p.PanelID, p.PanelCode, p.PanelName, e.EvaluatorID, e.PersonID, ppl.LastName, pApps.ApplicationID, ev.AnswerNumeric

from 
tblpanels p inner join tblEvaluators e on p.PanelID = e.PanelID
inner join tblPeople ppl on ppl.PersonID = e.PersonID
inner join tblPanelApps pApps on pApps.PanelID = p.PanelID
inner join tblEvaluations ev on ev.ApplicationID = pApps.ApplicationID and ev.EvaluatorID = e.EvaluatorID

where 
p.PanelID in (1234, 3656)
)tmp
PIVOT
(
max(AnswerNumeric)
For LastName IN (' + @cols + ')
) As P 
Order By PanelID, ApplicationID'
execute(@query)
```

The output is coming as

```
+=========+===========+===========+=============+==========+===============+======+=======+
| PanelID | PanelCode | PanelName | EvaluatorID | PersonID | ApplicationID | John | Carol |
+=========+===========+===========+=============+==========+===============+======+=======+
|    1234 |  12123412 | Panel A   |        3674 |     4834 |        112233 | 6    | NULL  |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------------+------+-------+
|    1234 |  12123412 | Panel A   |        3674 |     4834 |        112233 | NULL | 4     |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------------+------+-------+
```

It should be one row only per ApplicationID. How can I fix this query for below output?

```
+=========+===========+===========+=============+==========+===============+======+=======+
| PanelID | PanelCode | PanelName | EvaluatorID | PersonID | ApplicationID | John | Carol | Total
+=========+===========+===========+=============+==========+===============+======+=======+
|    1234 |  12123412 | Panel A   |        3674 |     4834 |        112233 | 6    | 4     | 10
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------------+------+-------+
```

EDIT: I also need a total score at the end for each row.

Comment: I cannot format the display properly.

Comment: You probably have strings that look the same but are different.

Comment: remove `, ev.AnswerNumeric` column in the sub select and try again

Comment: I get an error - Invalid column name 'AnswerNumeric'. In the PIVOT we are using AnswerNumeric

Comment: I also need a Total Score. Sum of all the values of the dynamic columns

Comment: Anyone? I am still stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The evaluatorID and the PersonID were causing the issue. I took them off from the subquery and it is now fixed. I also added the Total column. The updated query is

```
set @query = 'select PanelID, PanelCode, PanelName, ApplicationID, 
' + @cols + ', (ISNULL(' + REPLACE(@cols, ',', ',0.) + ISNULL(') + ',0.)) AS TOTAL from (
select 
distinct p.PanelID, p.PanelCode, p.PanelName, pApps.ApplicationID, ppl.LastName, isnull(ev.AnswerNumeric, 0) as AnswerNumeric

from 
tblpanels p inner join tblEvaluators e on p.PanelID = e.PanelID
inner join tblPeople ppl on ppl.PersonID = e.PersonID
inner join tblPanelApps pApps on pApps.PanelID = p.PanelID
left join tblEvaluations ev on ev.ApplicationID = pApps.ApplicationID and ev.EvaluatorID = e.EvaluatorID

where 
p.PanelID in (1234, 3656)
)tmp
PIVOT
(
max(AnswerNumeric)
For LastName IN (' + @cols + ')
) As P
Order By PanelID, ApplicationID'
--print @query
execute(@query)
```